# How To Access New Controller Via URL Path - C# / MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Complete beginner at C# MVC 4 - just trying to learn its basic structure. Currently if I run this project:

[image]

The page and URL look like this:

[image]

Apparently the code that sets this path as the default URL for the home page is in /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs, lines 22 and 23:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Now say that I want to enter a path that doesn't exist yet, like this:

`localhost:64653/home/foo`

What do I need to do in order to create this path? Would I need to create a `foo.cshtml` file within views? What else do I need to add to the `Controllers` folder in order to allow this view to exist? Thank you!

Comment: Create an action in the home controller named foo. In the Home folder under the view folder create a view named `foo.cshtml`. Most importantly, before posting something like this, you should check the documentation(or any other getting started tutorial) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here   `localhost:64653/home/foo`  means `foo action` in `home controller` you just have to create `action`  in `home controller` like this

```
public ActionResult foo()
{
  return view();
}
```

and also create a `view` of `foo.cshtml` in `home` folder so when you enter `localhost:64653/home/foo` in the `URL` the `default route` will know there is action name `foo` in `home` controller. You should also check these links

[creating a controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-controller-cs), [creating an action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-an-action-cs) and [adding a view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view). If you are new to `MVC` you should check these documents [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 1):

Create the action result in your Home controller:

```
public ActionResult foo()
{
  return view();
}
```

then right click the "view()" in the return statement, select create view.

It would also be extremely helpful if you did not ask questions that are documented in every single tutorial ever made about the mvc framework.

Comment: I don't have an option to select 'create view' when clicking "view()" 

http://i.imgur.com/LR3xR2D.png

The tutorial that I'm watching on pluralsight doesn't explain this. What tutorial would you suggest that does?

Comment: In the img you just posted you are LITERALLY hovering over the "Add View" command. All you have to do is click it and it will create the view for you.

Comment: Welcome.and for tutorials, go check out any of scott hanselman's work.